# How can I check Adjacency List hierarchy validity in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, validation, hierarchy

I store large hierarchies in my MS SQL database using the Adjacency List format. Each item has an `IndexNumber` and a `ParentIndexNumber` column. The IndexNumber column stores the sequence number for each item and the ParentIndexNumber can be used to calculate the hierarchy depth.

There is a very rare bug that destroys the validity of the hierarchy so I would like to have an SQL script to test for validity for easy testing and validation. Below is an example of an invalid hierarchy:

```
| IN | PIN  |       |
|----|------|-------|
| 3  | NULL |       |
| 4  | 3    |       |
| 5  | 3    |       |
| 6  | 4    | FAIL! |
| 7  | 6    |       |
```

IndexNumber 6 fails because all descendants of IndexNumber 4 should have an IndexNumber greater than 4 but they should never exist after a sibling of IndexNumber 4, like IndexNumber 5. I get the data used with a simple select like the one below but could I test for validity? Going through the data manually is very time consuming with larger datasets and multiple databases. The hierarchy can be 7 layers deep.

```
SELECT
    IndexNumber, ParentTopicIndexNumber
FROM
    Items
ORDER BY IndexNumber;
```

Comment: I don't really even know what kind of query to use, maybe a select with a very complicated where clause, but no idea where to start. If this is too broad - fine, it can be closed but I'm hoping for help or pointers :)

Comment: You will need a recursive common table expression for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e6f5/1 But I don't really understand why 19/4 is a fail. `indexnumber = 19` is a **direct** descendant of `4`. So it _is_ "below" 4.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Cheers, I'll have a look at that and start fiddling. I simplified the example, maybe now it's more clear; 6 cannot be a child of 4 because 5 is a sibling of 4 and thus terminates list of descendants that 4 must have. Does that explanation make sense? If you try to render the hierarchy in your head, does it make sense to you? We can assume that 1 and 2 have NULL parents. IndexNumber is not a random ID, but denotes the order that the items must be in.

Comment: I need the IndexNumber to keep track of the order that sibling items exist in. If that would not be necessary, I would use IDs instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in your fiddle example you kind of render the tree paths and then it would be possible to check validity by examining if the IDX column is sequential from 1 to n without any unordered items and without skipped numbers. I hope I have explained this clearly enough.